# Renaming array keys that differ on each run

Tags: php, arrays, key, rename

This is driving me mad.. I have a PHP script that returns an array in the form $key => $value and I want to rename the key so that I can display it in a table header. I saw there are several ways of doing this but I'm not sure they are what I need... Either that or I haven't understood the examples correctly which is the likely problem.

Basically my array keys differ each time I iterate over a foreach loop and also some can be blank. How can I get round this?

The first output might look like this:

```
'_can_chaccess' => false,
  '_can_chown' => false,
  '_can_delete' => false,
  '_can_modify' => false,
  '_can_read' => true,
  'assigned_to_name_879' => 'Unassigned',
  'id' => 1,
  'type' => 'Private::Reporting::DataViewModel::DataView_223_42858',
  'type_877' => 'Email',
```

The next run through, I might get this:

```
'_can_chaccess' => false,
  '_can_chown' => false,
  '_can_delete' => false,
  '_can_modify' => false,
  '_can_read' => true,
  'assigned_to_name_793' => 'Consultants',
  'id' => 1,
  'object_reference_794' => 'CASE-1004',
  'summary_795' => 'Deployment of New System for HQ (Project)',
  'type' => 'Private::Reporting::DataViewModel::DataView_200_42858',
),
```

As you can see, some keys rename the same e.g. id, type. But the most important ones that I am interested in change each time e.g. Assigned To Name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out using the below:

```
 $mappings_array = array();

    foreach ($report['data'][0] as $key => $value) {
        $workbooks->log('Old Key', $key);
        preg_match_all('([^_\d]+)', $key, $new_key);
        $workbooks->log('New Key', $new_key);
        $str = implode(" ", $new_key[0]);
        $capitalised = ucwords($str);
        array_push($mappings_array,$capitalised);
    }
```

Maybe it's not the best solution but it works :) I get the following output:

```
> New array: «array (
  0 => 'Can Chaccess',
  1 => 'Can Chown',
  2 => 'Can Delete',
  3 => 'Can Modify',
  4 => 'Can Read',
  5 => 'Id',
  6 => 'Total Type',
  7 => 'Type',
  8 => 'Type',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you receive your data from?

You can either somehow modify the source of your data, so if it were a query (what I do not assume here), you have the *SELECT ... AS ...* statement.

First you do need to know how to interpret the changing keys. If e.g. "assigned_to_name_879" and "assigned_to_name_793" is the same field, you can define a canonical function, which mapps both inputs to a unique output.

The output of the cannonical function and as well the other array keys can serve as keys for an additional array, which contains the table headers of your output.

So your current array is the value's array, and by hand you define a header's array:

array(
 'assigned_to_name_879' => 'Name assignment'
);

This dynamic way of storing the table headers in an array only makes sense if you are using the array twice. Otherwise you could simply write the header in the html-code which you do output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I am unable to modify the source, I am using a CRM API to retrieve the data and that's the response I get back. Both variations of the assigned to field will be the same.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would write the above, I understand the concept.. it's just the syntax that I struggle with.

Comment: What do you need code for exactly. Say it in your own wwords please because my answer contains more than one idea.

Comment: I'm retrieving a report from a MYSQL database where the field names are unique to the report, so each time I iterate over a foreach loop, I return a different report and thus different column headers. The column headers were displayed to the user in a table of results and thus having assigned_to_name_769 or whatever didn't really make sense to the user. Using the example below, I managed to format this into something more user friendly.